# Adomd connection to cube via http doesn't work after restarting the machine

Tags: c#, http, ssas, cube, adomd.net

I've the following code. It's pretty simple. First connect to ssas via http and than get the cube list. It works good until i restart my machine. After restart i get a strange exception (UnknownadomdException) like : incorect data format, and of course i have not the cube list at the end.

But, when after restart i run the Excel i'm able to connect to my ssas with the same connection parameters. After this i can also connect to my ssas in my code.

Do u have any idea?

```
           List<string> cubeList = new List<string>();

           using (AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection(@"Provider=MSOLAP.4;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=domain.local\userolap;Password=pass;Initial Catalog=ssas;Data Source=http://ssas-server.pl/directory/msmdpump.dll; MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error"))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    foreach (var cube in conn.Cubes)
                    {
                        if (cube.Name.StartsWith("$")) continue;
                        cubeList.Add(cube.Name);
                    }
                }catch (AdomdException exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with authentication. To confirm this, I would temporarily allow anonymous access in the configuration of the msmdpump IIS configuration and omit the user name and password from the connection string. If everything works then, you know it must be something in this area. This does not solve the issue, but may be give a direction for search of the reason.

Comment: Thank for comment. Actually i forget about one very important question. Its a problem with authentication for sure. My IIS and SSAS are on different machines. I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917670.aspx
Number 3. So it is it. I've to check my IIS configuration.

Comment: OK. problem solved! I have had on my IIS Basic and Windows Authentication. I have had disable Windows Authentication and looks that it is working. Thanks FrankPI for help.